# ag-grid react: gridApi is undefined

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am attempting to use the function sizeColumnsToFit() from the Grid API for my ag-grid table. When calling this function, I receive the error that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sizeColumnsToFit' of undefined"

I am attempting basically recreate the example in this link: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/ but it seems like the onGridReady function is not defining this.gridApi properly

```
...
onGridReady = (params) => {
    this.api = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi = params.gridApi;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.gridApi;
  }

render(){
...
//defining columns and rows
this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
return (
    <div
    className="ag-theme-balham"
style={{
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%          
    }}>

<AgGridReact
  columnDefs={columns}
      rowData={rows}
      onGridReady= {this.onGridReady}>
    </AgGridReact>
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this.gridApi is out of the scope of the AgGridReact object if its outside of the render function or within the functions for the ag grid. Instead of the above configuration, I called the function in the onGridReady function and it works just fine!